# iOS 16 specific issue: on tapping a push notification other notifications with the same title and body get also removed

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Firstly, on iOS 16 we have noticed that, *sometimes*, on tapping a push notification in the Notification Center other push notifications with the same `title` and `body` (in `UNMutableNotificationContent`) also get removed.

We want to display push notifications that show the same text to the user and with a similar or different image (`UNNotificationAttachment`). There are other other unique values in for several keys in the `payload` in the `userInfo` of the `UNMutableNotificationContent`.

Secondly, when using [removeDeliveredNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649500-removedeliverednotifications) with a specific identifier, all notifications with the same `title` and `body` will also be removed from the Notification Center.

To fix solve these two issues (to prevent that other notifications with the same `title` and `body` get removed) I would now have to add a random text to the body. This is not something we want to show to the user. I tried setting a unique `categoryIdentifier` and/or `threadIdentifier`, but still push notifications with the same title and body in the `UNMutableNotificationContent` get removed simultaneously.

Before iOS 16 notification with equal title and body do never get removed, I tested the exact same flows on iOS 12, 14 and 15. I also made sure that the notifications are not removed because we could be setting `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to zero, as is suggested in other answers to similar questions like mine on Stackoverflow.

Is anyone experiencing this behaviour also, or am I missing something new or a configuration on iOS 16 that causes it?